# Python - typing - union of subscriptable type

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, type-hinting, mypy

I'd like to create an `Array` type which should be **subscriptable** and be a Union of `typing.List` and `numpy.ndarray` types.
I know `numpy` doesn't come with stubs, but [those numpy stubs](https://github.com/machinalis/mypy-data/tree/master/numpy-mypy) (by *Machinalis*) should work fine as they are subsriptable.

This is the expected behavior:

```
def foo(bar: Array[int])->None:
    pass

foo([1,2,3])          # No typing error
foo(numpy.arange(4))  # No typing error
foo((1,2,3))          # Error: Expected Array[int], got Tuple[int]
foo([1.,2.,3.])       # Error: Expected Array[int], got Array[float]
```

I've tried a few things but none of them work as expected.

How would you do that in Python **3.7**?

I'll also accept some kind of duck-typing solution, even if it doesn't satisfy the Tuple error. The main point of focus is to create subscriptable union of subscriptable types.

Thanks.

My best attempt : (mypy errors in comments)

```
class _meta_getitem(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, x):
        return cls.__getitem__(cls, x)

class Array(metaclass=_meta_getitem):

    def __getitem__(self, element_type: type) -> type:
        array_type = typing.Union[List[element_type],  # error: Invalid type "element_type"
                                  numpy.ndarray[element_type]]
        return typing.NewType("Array[{}]".format(element_type.__name__), 
                              array_type)  # The type alias to Union is invalid in runtime context

if __name__ == "__name__":
    x: Array[int] = numpy.arange(4) # "Array" expects no type arguments, but 1 given
```

Comment: `Union[List[int], numpy.ndarray[int]]` doesn't work? What *did* you try?

Comment: It does works (it's what I use for the moment) but I'd like a generic, cleaner solution, meaning I define `Array` somewhere I can use `Array[int]`, `Array[float]`, `Array[Bar]` or whatever without having to define a special type each element type.
I've tried this :
using a `metaclass`, creating a *subscriptable* `Array` class which `__getitem__` method takes a `type` as argument and return the `Union`

Comment: Ah, OK, so you want to "factor out" the indexing, e.g. `Union[List, ndarray][int]` instead of `Union[List[in], ndarray[int]]` (and then basically make `Array` an alias for `Union[List, ndarray]`).

Comment: Yes, exactly but the obvious solution `Array = typing.Union[List, numpy.ndarray]` doesn't work.

i. e. `x: Array[int] = [1, 2]` raises `error: Bad number of arguments for type alias, expected: 0, given: 1`

Comment: Right, sorry, I meant that as pseudocode, not an actual solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Creating a type alias of `Union[List[T], Array[T]]` ought to work:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, List

T = TypeVar('T')
Array = Union[List[T], numpy.ndarray[T]]

def foo(bar: Array[int]) -> None: pass
```

See the mypy docs on [generic type aliases](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-type-aliases) for more info about this technique.

This code may potentially fail at runtime since `numpy.ndarray` isn't actually subscriptable at runtime, only in the type-hinting world. You can work around this by hiding your custom type hint behind a `typing.TYPE_CHECKING` guard, which is always false at runtime and true at type-check time.

You can do this relatively cleanly in Python 3.7+:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Union, List, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    T = TypeVar('T')
    Array = Union[List[T], numpy.ndarray[T]]

def foo(bar: Array[int]) -> None: pass
```

You have to wrap your `Array[int]` inside of a string for older versions of Python 3, however:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Union, List, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    T = TypeVar('T')
    Array = Union[List[T], numpy.ndarray[T]]

def foo(bar: "Array[int]") -> None: pass
```

---

Note that attempting to construct your own `Array` type hint by composing together several other type hints at runtime is unlikely to work: static analysis tools like mypy work by actually analyzing your code without running it: it's not actually going to attempt to evaluate anything inside of your custom `Array` class.

A little more generally speaking, attempting to "use" type hints at runtime tends to be fraught with peril: they're really only meant to be used as type hints.

Finally, you appear to be misunderstanding what `NewType` is for. I recommend reading [the relevant docs for more info](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#newtypes).

Comment: Thanks for this good answer, I'm indeed not very familiar with python typing module. I think this works fine, I've actually realized my stub file for `numpy` is not properly handled by mypy and is converted to `Any`. I'll validate your answer once I get things to work together and check if this works as expected.

Comment: For therestofus who learn from examples, could you point to some good examples of `typing` in the numpy / scipy world ?
(too soft for a new question) Thanks